# Cannot click on contents desplayed in IFRAME of dynamics crm form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2016, custom-pages

I've added an IFRAME on Accounts form of Dynamics CRM that is actually grabbing the contents from my custom page. But I am unable to click any of the hyperlink displayed in the IFRAME. Any workaround to make the contents accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to uncheck the "Restrict cross-frame scripting" option in the IFRAME properties:

[image]